# Google apps script: Create a new document and send it using Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to create a document and then send it using Gmail. Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
var doc = DocumentApp.create('My document');
doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This is the file that i want to receive');
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
GmailApp.sendEmail('address@gmail.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached        file.', {attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
 });
}
```

The file was created in my Google drive with the appended paragraph, the file id in doc.getId() is correct (using Logger.log() function). The problem is I **always receive a blank pdf** instead. I only could get the correct pdf file when change the code to manually input the file id in the :
file = DriveApp.getFileById('1b-XpCUmmn020Vav6psp4aZnenyzyVCm6tcj1-TlvWyU');

What did i do wrong in the code? Thank you very much for your responses!

Comment: You can use `Logger.log()` to view output of your code.  For example: if you add the line:  `Logger.log('What is the ID? ' + file);` then after the code has run, use the `view` menu, and view the logs.  Since the code only works if you hard code the ID, I'm curious to know what your variable `file` is returning?

Comment: I used the Logger.log() function and it showed the correct id. The problem happened because i didn't save the file as pointed out by Fabricator. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

Save the file before sending it. Also `doc` and `DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId())` actually refer to the same thing.

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('My document');
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This is the file that i want to receive');
  doc.saveAndClose();
  GmailApp.sendEmail('address@gmail.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached        file.', {attachments: [doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],name: 'Automatic Emailer Script' });
}
```

Comment: It worked like charm! I have the same problem when dealing with google spreadsheet. And the spread sheet doesn't have saveAndClose() function. Do you know how to deal with it? Thank you very much.

Comment: @QuanNguyen, try [flusing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) the changes.

Comment: I had the same issue and it worked, thanks.

Comment: I was having the blank PDF problem too.  ```saveAndClose()``` fixed it.  Thanks!