# PDF attachment sent with Gmail of Google doc is blank

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, gmail, google-docs

My goal is to attach a PDF version of a google doc in a Gmail attachment. I have generated the document with apps script and saved it in a folder in Drive. The email is sent with an attachment in PDF, but the pdf file contains nothing (it is completely blank). The relevant code I'm using:

```
 var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(docID).getAs("application/pdf"); // problem line?

 GmailApp.sendEmail(clientEmail, 'subject', 'Please see the attached file.', { 
       attachments: [blob],
       name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
   });
```

And I have already tried using the code from Google here:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(docID);
MailApp.sendEmail(clientEmail, 'Attachment example', 'Please see attached.', {
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]  // something going on here?
});
```

In both instances I recieve an email with a PDF attachement with the correct filename, but it is completely blank and doesn't contain the content of the (google doc) document it was supposedly generated from. Am I missing something when creating the blob? Are there document-specific parameters I need to correctly generate the blob?

I'm obviously missing something - sorry if it is very obvious!

Comment: I have tried your code (both) and it worked fine with a google doc to pdf. Do you have anything else on the script? Can you try creating a new script with just the code you provided?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I found that the problem was that the doc needed to be saved and closed using doc.saveAndClose(). I found the answer here for anyone in future:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441646/google-apps-script-create-a-new-document-and-send-it-using-gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been found on this post:

[Google apps script: Create a new document and send it using Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441646/google-apps-script-create-a-new-document-and-send-it-using-gmail)

The document has to be saved one time to be able to be emailed.

Using the function [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose) on the script saves the document before sending it in case you want to send a newly generated document.